# How to configure schema to accept xml document with namespaces without prefixes

Tags: xml, validation, schema, biztalk

I am receiving a document that has the following structure:

```
<Postnumre xmlns="http://Customer.Vejregister.Schemas.Vejregister_PostNr_XML.PostNr_XML">
    <Postnr xmlns="http://Customer.Vejregister.Schemas.Vejregister_PostNr_XML.PostNr_XML">
        <Sekvensnummer>sekvensnummer</Sekvensnummer>
        <Tidspunkt>tidspunkt</Tidspunkt>
        <Operation>operation</Operation>
        <PostNr>nr</PostNr>
        <PostnrNavn>navn</PostnrNavn>
        <Stormodtager>stormodtager</Stormodtager>
    </Postnr>
    <Postnr xmlns="http://Customer.Vejregister.Schemas.Vejregister_PostNr_XML.PostNr_XML">
        <Sekvensnummer>1</Sekvensnummer>
        <Tidspunkt>2014-08-20T11:17:50.644Z</Tidspunkt>
        <Operation>insert</Operation>
        <PostNr>0800</PostNr>
        <PostnrNavn>Høje Taastrup</PostnrNavn>
        <Stormodtager>1</Stormodtager>
    </Postnr>
</Postnumre>
```

As you can see, it has the same namespace on the root node and all child nodes without prefixes.

On my schema I've set the targetNamespace to the above namespace, but when validating the instance of this document against the schema, I get a "Validate instance failed" message returned.

Is it possible to configure my schema to allow documents of this kind? I'm unsure why it fails, since I am using the same namespace.

Schema code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Customer.Vejregister.Schemas.Vejregister_PostNr_XML.PostNr_XML" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Customer.Vejregister.Schemas.Vejregister_PostNr_XML.PostNr_XML" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Postnumre">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Postnr">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Sekvensnummer" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Tidspunkt" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Operation" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="PostNr" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="PostnrNavn" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Stormodtager" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Hi Leth. Did my answer help resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I generated a schema from your sample XML and it produced the bellow schema.

The key difference is that it has added `elementFormDefault="qualified"` which you can set via clicking on the `<Schema>` at the top and setting Element FormDefault to Qualified.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://Customer.Vejregister.Schemas.Vejregister_PostNr_XML.PostNr_XML" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Postnumre">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Postnr">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Sekvensnummer" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Tidspunkt" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Operation" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="PostNr" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="PostnrNavn" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Stormodtager" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```